# Watir WebDriver transparent screenshots

Tags: ruby, webdriver, screenshot, watir, watir-webdriver

Using watir WebDriver in ruby to pull up instances of firefox and take screenshots. Tried all manner of headless solutions but they would not render with typekit web fonts. Now I have this working, but 1 thing I would really like, a transparent background!

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto "#{URL}"
browser.driver.save_screenshot "screenshots/#{font}.png"
browser.close
```

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem.

Comment: I think you get a screenshot of the web page & web pages can't have transparent backgrounds, so you're stuck

Comment: Ah ok. I know that the headless phantom js does transparency, but that must only be headless screenshots that support it, but they don't support the rendering of web fonts. I am sure we can setup some form of automated action in Photoshop to do the transparency.